# Java Regex to find if a given String contains a set of characters in the same order of their occurrence.

Tags: regex, string, contains, find-occurrences

We need Java Regex to find if a given String contains a set of characters in the same order of their occurrence.

E.g. if the given String is `"TYPEWRITER"`,

the following strings should return a match:

`"YERT"`, `"TWRR"` & `"PEWRR"` (character by character match in the order of occurrence),

**but not**

`"YERW"` or `"YERX"` (this contains characters either not present in the given string or doesn't match the order of occurrence).

This can be done by character by character matching in a for loop, but it will be more time consuming. A regex for this or any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all REGEX has nothing to do with it. Regex is powerful but not that much powerful to accomplish this.

The thing you are asking is a part of [Longest Common Subsequence(LCS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) Algorithm implementation. For your case you need to change the algorithm a bit. I mean instead of matching part of string from both, you'll require to match your one string as a whole subsequence from the Larger one.

The LCS is a dynamic algorithm and so far this is the fastest way to achieve this. If you take a look at the [LCS Example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Example) here you'll find that what I am talking about.